can uninstalling MSYS2 be a raison to have my files gone?
Uninstalling MSYS2 can lose your files
So I installed MSYS2 in "Documents" path and after a while I decided to uninstall it but I have got surprised  while I was doing that cuz I found out that all my file in "document folder" gone?
How can I get them back? Please guys they are so important to me .

I always install MSYS2 at C:/msys64.  It would probably be fine to install it in a subdirectory of your Documents folder like C:/Users/yacine/Documents/msys2 (though I do NOT recommend this).  If you literally installed MSYS2 at the top level of your Documents folder then the MSYS2 uninstaller would probably just assume everything in that folder is part of MSYS2 and then delete it.  Yikes!

Oof, that's a painful situation - I feel for you. I've seen this happen before with MSYS2 installations in protected Windows directories. Here's what you can do:
1.  STOP using your computer right now - any new files you create might overwrite the deleted data
2.  First thing first - check your Recycle Bin. Sometimes Windows is smart enough to catch the deletions there.
3.  If that's empty (which it probably is), you'll need data recovery software. I've had good results with Recuva (it's free) or EaseUS Data Recovery (paid but more powerful).
4.  Pro tip: For future reference, NEVER install MSYS2 or similar Unix-like environments in Windows system folders or document directories. Always use a separate dedicated folder like C:\msys64 or similar.
The reason this happened is because MSYS2's uninstaller can sometimes get confused with path handling between Windows and Unix-style paths, leading to accidental deletions outside its install directory. It's a known issue that pops up occasionally.
Quick steps for recovery:

Download recovery software (Recuva is a good free option)
Install it on a DIFFERENT drive than where your files were lost
Run a deep scan on your Documents folder
Recover what you can find
Hope you can get your files back! And remember for next time - always keep backups of important files (learned this the hard way myself ).

